# Binding a checker in SystemVerilog

Tags: bind, system-verilog, modelsim, questasim

I would like to bind a checker construct to a VHDL module (in QuestaSim) to ensure some verification properties, without having to declare and bind a more (complex) module/interface/agent structure.
Without further ado I present you the example code I was using:

```
module verification_top();
  ...
  bind dut_wrapper.dut test_checker tc();
  ...
endmodule

checker test_checker();
  ...
endchecker
```

The vopt error is:
`** Error: src/tb_vtop.sv(210): Failed to instantiate checker 'test_checker' inside bind's target 'dut_wrapper'.
Optimization failed`

Binding modules and interfaces work well with the same testbench, syntax and tool.

As far as I understand the 1800-2012 LRM 23.11 specifies that checkers can be bound inside modules. I would like to inquire the collective knowledge: is this a tool related limitation (not supported construct) or is there a special requirement for checkers to be able to get bound. I have consulted MG's QuestaSim user manual and command reference manual, but checkers and bind constructs are usually unmentioned.

I know I have several workaround options, the question relates the checker construct itself, as I have never used it before.

Comment: To be honest, I think you're just pushing the envelope. I think your work around is going to be required.

Comment: Yep, I feel the same. Thank you for your comment anyway. :)

Comment: Why don't you use a module instead of a checker?

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal to have concurrent assertions in classes. 
Your best bet is to either user the checkers or write the assertions in the interface, or in a module (or checker) bound to t. 
Ben Cohen systemverilog.us

Comment: Yep, although I can write a custom agent with immediate assertions that mimic the concurrent assertions' intent if I would like to choose that way.